# Handling frequent message transmission to a remote endpoint in RPMsg communication

Tags: ipc, embedded-linux

I am working with an RPMsg communication setup and frequently sending messages to a remote endpoint.Does sending messages frequently to a remote endpoint in RPMsg communication overwrite the previous data? If so, the sender should get first an ack for each successfully received and processed message from the receiver. Can someone please clarifiy?